# How can I use input value as font-size?

Tags: input, fonts

How can I use input value as font-size in HTML?

Like `<p class="blahblahblah" style="font-size: 120px"> blah blah </p>`

I want to change "120px" as the value of the input tag

Comment: Not possible in pure HTML, you need to use Javascript

Comment: Yes I know but how I can use Javascript to change to the size as the value of the input tag

Answer (score 0):

I did a working example in vanilla JS:

```js
function changeFontSize(){
  var size = document.getElementById('sizer').value;
  document.getElementById('target').style.fontSize = size + "px";
}
```

```html
<input id="sizer" onChange="changeFontSize()"/>

<p id="target"> blah blah </p>
```